# How to tell SQL Server to interpret bad numeric field as zero

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query below that fails because some rows cannot be interpreted as numbers. Somebody put alphabet characters in the quantity column. I want those to be taken as if they were zero (just like I did for NULL with cast).

How would I accomplish this?

```
Select 
    DocId, AR_Numbers, PONO, Product, 
    Sum(Cast(ISNULL(Quantity, 0) as decimal)) as Qty 
from 
    (Select 
         ARs.DocID, Ars.Field61 as AR_Numbers, PONOs.Field21 as PONO, 
         CoreData.Field9 as Product, CoreData.Field10 as Quantity 
     from 
         ssMVFields ARs 
     left join 
         ssFields PONOs on ARs.DocId = PONOs.DocId 
     left join 
         ssField14 as CoreData on Ars.DocID = CoreData.DocID) as AAA
Group by 
    DocId, AR_Numbers, PONO, Product
```

Comment: Change the data type of the column to a numeric type and set the default value as 0.

Comment: I am with @juergend, the only proper action is to fix the data model. It is irresponsible to store data that must be numeric in a varchar, nvarchar field.

Comment: How does that sub-query serve any purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`try_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) is just right for that:

```
isnull(try_cast(quantity as int), 0)
```

Comment: This is a good idea for fixing the existing data in an update, but should never be used to avoid fixing the underlying problem of the bad datatype in a select. This adds additional, unnecessary load to your server every time you want to use the numbers as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TRY_CAST to try to cast the field to numeric, it will return null if it fails and then you can replace the null with a 0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where in your query you need to do that but you can use a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourFieldHere) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE YourFieldHere END
```

This checks if filed is numeric, and if it is not returns 0.  This should work for most/all numbers including decimal.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that SQL Server sometimes evaluates an expression in the wrong branch, and that can raise an exception. I.e. `cast(case when isnumeric(col1) then col1 else 1 end as int)` can unexpectedly throw for non-numeric `col1` values

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this query.  But fundamentally, I recommend `try_convert()`:

```
select DocId, Ars.Field61 as AR_Numbers, PONOs.Field21 as PONO,
       CoreData.Field9 as Product, 
       sum(try_convert(decimal, CoreData.Field10)) as Qty
from ssMVFields ARs left join
     ssFields PONOs
     on ARs.DocId = PONOs.DocId left join
     ssField14 CoreData
     on Ars.DocID = CoreData.DocID
group by DocId, Ars.Field61, PONOs.Field21, CoreData.Field9
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ISNUMERIC('Fieldvalue')` check before casting

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).